# Word count in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, string, angularjs

I am trying to write a quick program that counts the number of words in AngularJS. Basically a textarea in HTML and underneath it should display the number of words as the user inputs them.

So this is my HTML code:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html ng-app>
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wordcount.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="wordCount">
        <label>Copy and Paste your text:</label><br>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="20" ng-model="mytext"></textarea>
        <hr>
        <span>{{wordCount()}} word(s)</span>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Javascript file called wordcount.js (to count the number of words in a given string):

```
function wordCount($scope) {
    $scope.numberofwords = function(s) {
        s = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
        s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
        s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
        s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
        return s.split(' ').length;
    }
}
```

I basically found the above on http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/text/count-words.html

So I have probably not fully understood how to use AngularJS (and the JS code is probably wrong too) to update the number of words instantly. Right now it doesn't show anything but "words".

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why are you doing replacements , when you want a match count? '/\b(\w+)\b/g'  s.match(regex) gives you an array.. which can then have a .length operator to u the number of matches. you could also separate by non words \S instead of boundary \b.. This is covered in regular expressions and w3cschool regex for javascript.

Comment: I'd do what alexmac said, and shouldn't you be operating on `$scope.mytext` since you don't have an ID on your `<textarea>` element?

Comment: EVen if you do have an ID on the `textarea` element, you should definitely be operating on `$scope.mytext`. Fetching an element from the DOM is expensive, and the whole philosophy behind Angular is that you shouldn't be doing that. use the model, instead of the view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of correct way is to use a $scope function:

```
<body ng-controller="WCController">
    <h3>World count</h3>
    <div>total words: <span ng-bind="countOf(myText)"></span></div>
    <textarea ng-model="myText"></textarea>
</body>
```

and at the controller:

```
$scope.countOf = function(text) {
    var s = text ? text.split(/\s+/) : 0; // it splits the text on space/tab/enter
    return s ? s.length : '';
};
```

You can test this on plunker:
http://run.plnkr.co/Mk9BjXIUbs8hGoGm/

Comment: Great!. it is a simple one. but can you tell me how to limit to some number of words

Comment: @ThilakRaj you can to make a single loop: var out = ""; for(var c = 0; c < limit && c<s.length; c++) { out = (out) ? out + " " + s[c] : s[c] } to create a limited words string

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

- update a `wordCount` property when `myText` changes.
- use simple regexp in a String.prototype.match call.
- use this updated `wordCount` scope property in your template.

**Code**

Your watcher should look like something like that:

```
$scope.$watch('myText', function(text) {
    // no text, no count
    if(!text) {
        $scope.wordCount = 0;
    } 
    // search for matches and count them
    else {
        var matches = text.match(/[^\s\n\r]+/g);
        $scope.wordCount = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    }
});
```

**Important note**

> **Why computing the count in a watcher ?**
>
> > To prevent this count from being computed on each digestion, the way it is when you use such a `wordCount()` method call in your template !